# Javascript a recursive function with no clear base case?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am wondering, what is the best approach to write a recursive function with no direct base case (say: factorial), for instance, to count the number of elements in a nested array I have two approaches in mind, the first one below is preferred as it returns result directly:

[image: code as image]

the second one keeps the count in a variable attached to the function, works fine, but dealing with the result & resetting the variable is bizarre.

[image: code as image]

any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Posting screenshots of code isn't helpful.  Just paste the code in your question.

Comment: Why can't you just pass it as argument? Also, I am not sure to understand what's the role of a base for counting elements in an array.

Comment: Seriously, not being able to copy paste your code makes answering this question much harder.

Comment: The pictures are gone. That's why you should've pasted your code instead of posting images.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the value you are interested in:

```
function countElements(arr) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
      count += countElements(arr[i]); // recursion here
    } else {
      count++; // normal element counts as 1
    }    
  }
  return count;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ejEmOwEQ/1/edit

**WARNING**: The function might not end if the array contains self reference (`var arr = []; arr.push(arr); countElements(arr);`)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to write this is simply:

```
function countElements (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var count = 0;

        for (var i in obj)
            count += countElements(obj[i]);

        return count;
    }
    return 1
}
```

The terminating condition you're looking for is `if not instanceof Array`. Which in my code above is simply the fall through from the `if instanceof Array` block.

You do not need to keep a temp variable like `count` in recursive functions. You're still thinking iteratively (well, that for loop is iterative so you need a `count` variable there).

Recursive functions do everything by accepting arguments and returning results. No assignments are necessary. In fact, the code above can be written purely recursively without using a for loop and therefore without needing to use a `count` variable:

```
function countElements (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        if (obj.length) {
            return countElements(obj.shift()) + countElements(obj);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

There are 3 rules: if object is not an array we return 1, if object is an empty array we return 0 otherwise we count the first item in the array + the sum of the rest of the array.